# Copy files to a randomly named subdirectory

Tags: windows, shell, copy, random

i'm a complete amateur when it comes to shell scripts so a little out of my depth. But I have an existing script which is -almost- doing its job, and i'm hoping to edit it to make it work right.

So the entire contents of the existing script are thus

```
copy css\* "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache" /y
copy images\* "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache" /y
copy js\* "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache" /y
copy templates\* "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache" /y
```

Seems simple, its just copying all files from four subfolders, into a cache directory.
The problem is, that cache is not exactly where the files need to go. They need to go into a subfolder of that cache. But that subfolder has a randomly generated name, generally something like "tmpXXXX" with a random 4 digit number for the X
and it is deleted and remade (with a new randomly generated name) each session, so i can't just type in the subfolder here.

I can guarantee that there will only ever be one subfolder within cache. So i just need to find whatever folder is there and copy the files into it.

Any idea how i'd go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one folder under cache folder this `for loop` will copy results to only that folder. Actually it's `for loop` for every command. Switch `/D` will return folder names; in your case only one.

```
FOR /D %%i IN (%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache\*) DO (copy css\* %%i /y)
FOR /D %%i IN (%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache\*) DO (copy images\* %%i /y)
FOR /D %%i IN (%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache\*) DO (copy js\* %%i /y)
FOR /D %%i IN (%USERPROFILE%\Documents\BYOND\cache\*) DO (copy templates\* %%i /y)
```